# Перемешать значения в массиве

Tags: php

```
        $array = array('N1', 'N2', 'N3', 'N3', );

        for ($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
            echo $array[$i];
        }
```

Нужно, чтобы значения из массива всегда выводились в случайном порядке. Пробовал array_rand, но эта функция перемешивает только ключи массива.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.shuffle.php

Comment: Функция `array_rand` дает случайный порядок ключей из массива. Если пройтись по этому набору и вывести значения соответствующие ключам - тоже получите случайные последовательности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.shuffle.php

```
$array = array('N1', 'N2', 'N3', 'N3', );
shuffle($array);

for ($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    echo $array[$i];
}
```